# Traffic of specific program through vpn

Tags: iptables, firewall, raspbian, vpn, openvpn

is it possible to only let the traffic of Deluge through a VPN (OpenVPN) and the other traffic not with iptables?

Comment: iptables cannot tell one program from another: it uses only ports and addresses

Answer (score 2):

The Deluge User Guide has a page about that : [Setting up Deluge with VPN](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/VPN). Scripts for a basic torrent-VPN setup can be found on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/bendikro/deluge-vpn). The README.md file even has a little something about OpenVPN :

> To use these scripts with OpenVPN, make a clone of the repo and set the correct values for the interfaces and user in `vpn_base.sh`. Edit the openvpn client config and add this line:
>
> `up "/path/to/repo/link_up_user_filter.sh"`
>
> To allow executing external scripts automatically when starting the openvpn client, run openvpn with the argument `--script-security 2` or add this line to the client config:
>
> `script-security 2`

The "values" they are talking about in `vpn_base.sh` are the following:

```
VPNIF="tun0"
NETIF="eth1"
VPNUSER="vpnuser"
TABLE_ID=42
MARK_ID=0x10
```

I'm not very familiar with these scripts, but I'd guess they correspond to:

- The network interface for the VPN traffic.
- The network interface to the Internet.
- The user running the VPN software (`openvpn` in your case?)
- An available routing table ID.
- An available packet mark ID.

Once the setup is complete, the scripts should setup a few routing/firewall rules and your Deluge traffic should pass through OpenVPN.

**A word of warning though:** it seems these scripts flush the `nat`, `mangle` and `filter` tables in IPTables, which will erase any IPTables configuration you've made so far.

```
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -F -t filter
```

Make sure to save your tables with `iptables-save` first, or just edit the `user_filter/iptables_user_filter.sh` file.

If you want more information, here are a few links that might interest you:

- [How do I route traffic through specific interface for a specific process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66203/how-do-i-route-traffic-through-specific-interface-for-a-specific-process)
- [How to use Deluge anonymously](http://www.best-bittorrent-vpn.com/how-to-use-deluge-anonymously.html)
- [An Arch Linux Docker which runs Deluge over OpenVPN (GitHub)](https://github.com/binhex/arch-delugevpn)
- A blog post about [`it-netns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) : [Using Linux Network Namespaces for per processes routing](http://www.evolware.org/?p=293)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specifically target an application so the only solution with no dependencies is to create a iptables configuration that directs all the ports to your VPN. But you have to know what to forward and that is error prone.

A better solution would be to use Linux Containers and run your app inside. Then have the container's network card forward all traffic to the VPN. Here is a tutorial for Arch, but the basic concept applies to any distribution.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN_in_Linux_containers